# PHP increase number by one

Tags: php, math, numbers

This is a tricky one: I want to add +1 to this number: 012345675901 and the expected result is: `012345675902`. Instead I get: `2739134` when I do this:

```
echo (012345675901+1);
```

When I try:

```
echo ('012345675901'+1);
```

I get this: `12345675902` which is pretty close to what I need, but it removes the leading zero.

When I do this:

```
echo (int) 012345675901;
```

I get `2739133`. I also tried bcadd() without success:

```
echo bcadd(012345675901, 1);
```

which resulted in `2739134`.

I know I am missing something here. I would really appreciate your help!

**UPDATE 1**
Answer 1 says that the number is octal:

```
function is_octal($x) {
    return decoct(octdec($x)) == $x;
}

$number = is_octal(012345675901);
echo var_dump($number);
```

The above returns **false**. I thought I needed to convert this from octal to a normal string but didn't work. I can't avoid not using the above number - I just need to increment it by one.

**EDIT 2**

This is the correct code:

```
$str = '012345675901';

$str1 = ltrim($str, '0'); // to remove the leading zero
$str2 = bcadd($str1, 1); // +1 to your result
$str3 = strlen($str); // get the length of your first number
echo str_pad($str2, $str3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // apply zeros
```

Thank you everyone for your help! The above code produces: `012345675902` as expected

Comment: Try 0x in front of the number instead of just a humble 0 - then you get confused!

Comment: your function does the conversion too late - its already a number.

Comment: Where are you getting this number from, exactly? I'm assuming it's not hard-coded into your php script?

Comment: No it's not - I'm just trying out different inputs on a script with random data and check the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see the code for explanation.

```
$str = "012345675901"; // your number
$str1 = ltrim($str, '0'); // to remove the leading zero
$str2 = bcadd($str1, 1); // +1 to your result
$str3 = strlen($str); // get the length of your first number
echo str_pad($str2, $str3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // apply zeros
```

Comment: Thanks your code works pretty well, but it doesn't add the leading zeros.

Comment: I just did - see my updated question. Thank you so much for guiding me to the solution. Your approach works for my situation very well, so I will accept your answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 8):

The leading `0` is treating your number as octal.

The leading `0` you need for output as a string, is a purely a representation.

Comment: Indeed, and displaying it as base10. If you need octals, make strings with `decoct()`.

Comment: If the leading zero is omitted then the result is as expected.

Comment: @userid53 that's because its octal.